# How to add a line break in an Android TextView? \n not working

Tags: android, newline, line-breaks

I am getting data from xml for line break in following format;
line1 \n line2.but on setting this string in textview its displaying line1 \n line2 intead of; 
line1
line2. if i hardcode the the value in textview its giving correct result but getting data from xml is not showing properly...

Comment: Can you post the code where you're setting the TextView text?

Answer (score 3):

```
<string name="sample_string"><![CDATA[some test line 1 <br />some test line 2]]></string>
```

so wrap in CDATA is necessary and breaks added inside as html tags

Answer (score 2):

If you plan as using the string as HTML, you can use `&lt;br /&gt;` for a line break(`<br />`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">Hello&lt;br /&gt;World!</string>
</resources>
```

(or)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <string name="title">Hello\nWorld!</string>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both previous answers were almost there. The BR tag doesn't do so well with Android. However, `\n` works if you wrap it in a CDATA element as shown below.

In your strings.xml values file add this:

```
<string name="sample_string"><![CDATA[some test line 1 \nsome test line 2]]></string>`
```